# Firefox Rapid Release Mode and add-ons

Tags: firefox, compatibility, firefox-extensions, releases

Now that Firefox has entered in the [Rapid release mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Firefox#Change_of_release_cycle_after_4.0), I'm wondering at the implications on add-on compatibility front.

For example, will a working FF4 add-on (in my case, Firebug) still work after the upgrade to FF5?

Comment: That solely depends on the developers of each and every add on there is. There's no way to generally tell for every plugin. Whether the release cycle changes anything in the behavior of add-on developers pushing updates, that is pure speculation. Therefore voting to close as not constructive. Currently, Firebug [already supports FF5](https://getfirebug.com/downloads/), it shouldn't be so hard to look up on the add-on specific download pages whether they support a given version. Answers about what *currently* is supported is also too localized (it may change within days).

Comment: "That solely depends on the developers of each and every add on there is." would have been a very good answer!

Comment: Well I rather like to keep that in comments. As you can see, it already leads to speculation in the answers ;)

Comment: Check out this for this issue: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-on-compatibility-reporter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug 1.7.3 works for me - just upgraded to FF5 with no problems.

Whilst I agree with @slhck 's comment, my gut feeling would be that given Mozilla's rapid release intentions, I think changes to FF would be minimal and incremental so maybe add-ons would be less likely to be broken.